# How to solve java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid target position error?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

> I have a simple messaging layout, where Evertime anyone opens the Activity, then the recycler view should always show the Latest Data which is at the Bottom of the Screen.

> So, i found this code to do that :

```
 comment_recycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.comment_recycler);
 comment_recycler.smoothScrollToPosition(comment_recycler.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1);
```

> But, everytime this Error occurs :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid target position
```

> This is the complete code :

```
  databaseReference1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Blogs").child("Comments");
    options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<CommentModel>()
            .setQuery(databaseReference1, CommentModel.class)
            .build();

    comment_recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    commentAdapter = new CommentAdapter(options, CommentsActivity.this);
    comment_recycler.setAdapter(commentAdapter);
    comment_recycler.smoothScrollToPosition(comment_recycler.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1);
    commentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    commentAdapter.startListening();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    commentAdapter.stopListening();
}
```

> How to fix this Error . Please Guide. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the data is fetched from remote using asynchronous call, hence the initial `smoothScrollPosition` would be `-1` as `comment_recycler.getAdapter().getItemCount()` will be `zero` until the data is fetched, please move that line after the data is fetched and notified to `recycler`.

Comment: I moved to this :   comment_recycler.smoothScrollToPosition(commentAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
        commentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  inside OnResume() after listening, still error

Comment: Not inside onresume, you have to move it after fetching the data inside firebase callback in adapter

Answer (score 0):

Try `smoothScrollPosition` method when recyclerview data fully loaded.

So

```
comment_recycler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        comment_recycler.smoothScrollToPosition(comment_recycler.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1);
    }
},500);
```

500 is not measured value, but it will be works in most case.